# MATLAB: Reference iterated strings in variable names in Stata style

Tags: matlab, stata

In MATLAB, I want to perform a series of commands on a pair of datasets which group males and females separately -- and I want to export the results separately.  I'm familiar with Stata, so my instinct is to do something like this:

```
foreach X in m f{
    data_`X' = csvread('data_`X'.csv');
    variable_`X' = data_`X'(:,12);
    plot(1975:2011,variable_`X')
    print -djpeg graph_`X'
    % etc.
}
```

but I haven't been able to find an analog to that `X' quoting structure in MATLAB, which would allow the iterated string to be referred to as a part of a variable name.

I'm new to MATLAB, so I may be barking up the wrong tree entirely.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it may not be the most efficient.

Assuming that `m` is a cell array of strings, and data_X.csv exists:

```
for ii=1:length(m)
  assignin('base',['data_' m{ii}], csvread(evalin('base',['data_' m{ii} '.csv'));
  assignin('base',['variable_' m{ii}],['data_' m{ii} '(:,12)']);
  plot(1975:2011, evalin('base',['variable_' m{ii}]));
  ...
```

I think that will get you on the right track.